# How to convert json data into nested json data format?

Tags: java, json, treeview

```
[{"roleId":1,"roleName":"system Admin","createUser":"1","createActive":"N"},{"roleId":2,"roleName":"admin","createUser":"1","createActive":"Y"},{"roleId":3,"roleName":"system Admin","createUser":"1","createActive":"Y"}]
```

This is my Output written in spring using list but i want it in nested json format such that is tree view(structure) like following structure.

```
 [{ "id": 1, "data": "Category", "attr": { "id": "1", "selected": false }, "children":
                    [
                        { "id": 2, "data": "SubCategory1", "attr": { "id": "2", "selected": false }, "children":
                                [{ "id": 4, "data": "Item1", "attr": { "id": "4", "selected": false }, "children": [] },
                                 { "id": 5, "data": "Item2", "attr": { "id": "5", "selected": false }, "children": [] },
                                 { "id": 6, "data": "Item3", "attr": { "id": "6", "selected": false }, "children": [] }
                                ]
                        },

                        { "id": 3, "data": "SubCategory2", "attr": { "id": "3", "selected": false }, "children":
                                 [{ "id": 7, "data": "Item4", "attr": { "id": "7", "selected": false }, "children": [] },
                                  { "id": 8, "data": "Item5", "attr": { "id": "8", "selected": false }, "children": [] },
                                  { "id": 9, "data": "Item6", "attr": { "id": "9", "selected": false }, "children": [] }
                                 ]
                        }
                    ]
    }];
```

my code is,

```
    @GET
    @Path("/findall")
    public List<UserRole> getAll() {

         return userroleservice.findAll();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use pretty print with some Json parser like Gson

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
String json = gson.toJson(obj);
System.out.println(json);
```

If it is in webpage use javascript or [Jquery format plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/tag/pretty-print/)

```
var str = JSON.stringify(obj, null, 4);
```